# postaudit a HTML file

Tags: html, security, bash, audit

I have a generated HTML file, and I want to audit it, before uploading it to a website (a script does it, in every hour)

I want to audit for things like this: `<script>BADTHINGS</script>`

I can't use:

```
sed -i "s/<script>//g" htmlfile.html
```

Because there could be, e.g.:

```
<scr<script>ipt>BADTHINGS</scr</script>ipt>
```

What do you advise? How could I audit the HTML file?

PS. the htmlfile.html contains links to news, e.g.: slashdot, etc. <- the file is generated by a script.

Comment: Is *any* JavaScript allowed? (If not, then searching for `<script` should be sufficient.)

Comment: @middaparka no,  because `< script` also executes javascript :p

Comment: @Rook That's an exceptionally good point. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do multiple passes with sed, use HTMLPurifier.

Comment: +1 If he wants to remove all JS then HTMLPurifier is his best bet.  And you can run php from bash.